# HTML radiobutton color change

Tags: html, fonts, colors, radio-button

I think this is a pretty simple thing to do, but I don't know how.. thus I'm here. I have written a simple HTML form and need to change the color of the text on a Radio Button. Anyone have any ideas on how this is done?

Comment: Text on a radio button? That's a first to me!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<input type="radio" id="foo">
<label for="foo"> Blah Blah </label>
```

Now you select the LABEL via CSS and set it to have a color... You can use classes or relationship, for example:

```
.radioDiv label { color:blue; }
```

Answer (score 3):

Assuming the following HTML:

```
<input type="radio" name="group1" value="Milk" /><span>Milk</span>
```

Just either add a class to the span, or wrap it in a div and style that using basic CSS:

```
#somediv span
{
   color: red;
}
```